# Kivy RecycleView: how can we scroll to the end of the list

Tags: kivy

For example, after adding a new entry to the RecycleView data, how can we ensure the last added item is displayed at the bottom of the list without having to manually scroll down the list ?

Comment: You could probably use [goto_view](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.layout.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.layout.RecycleLayoutManagerBehavior.goto_view).

Comment: the body of the goto_view() method in kivy.uix.recycleview.layout only contains pass !

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of searching, I think that you can set the `scroll_y` property of `RecycleView` to `0`, and the last entry should then be at the bottom of the `RecycleView`.

Comment: `scroll_y` set to `0` works for scrolling to the end of the list, but it makes no sense; especially since I want to scroll to the top of the list after a `refresh_from_data`. How can I scroll to the top of the list?

Comment: Reading the documentation for `ScrollView` explained it. Y scrolling value, between 0 and 1. If 0, the content’s bottom side will touch the bottom side of the `ScrollView`. If 1, the content’s top side will touch the top side.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extract of the kv file applying the solution posted by John Anderson. Pay attention to the first comment ... :

```
BoxLayout:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "70dp"
    RecycleView:
        id: request_RecycleView_list
        size_hint_y: 1
        scroll_y: 0                     # forces scrolling to list bottom after adding an entry
        effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"      # prevents overscrolling
        viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'

        SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(20) # height of list line
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            spacing: 0.5
            orientation: 'vertical'
            multiselect: False
            touch_multiselect: False

<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1) if self.selected else (.0, 0.9, .1, .3)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.9, .1, .3)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```